# Show/Hide data on react with fetch API

Tags: json, reactjs, fetch

I am trying to get data from an API and show/hide it on react. I get the data fine but hide button doesn't work. Data is shown always. I am relatively new to react and really want to learn it. Here is my code: (And it would be great if anyone suggest where can I learn more about react on web)

```
import React from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';

class Series extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            showSeries: false
        };
    }

    render() {
        const serieses = this._GetList();
        let seriesNodes;
        let buttonText = 'Show Series';
        if (this.state.showMangas) {
            seriesNodes = <div>{serieses}</div>;
            buttonText = 'Hide Series';

        }
        return (<div>
                <button onClick={this._handleClick.bind(this)}>{buttonText}</button>
                {seriesNodes}
            </div>
        );
    }

    _GetList() {
        var myInit = {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: new Headers({
                'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
            }),
        }
        var myRequest = new Request('data.json', myInit);
        fetch(myRequest)
            .then(function (response) {
                return response.json()
                    .then(function (json) {
                        console.log(json)
                        json.manga.map((item) => {
                            var li = document.createElement('li');
                        //  for (var i = 0; i < (item).length; i++) {
                                li.innerHTML = 'Name: ' + item.t + ', Genre: ' + item.c + ' Hit Count: ' + item.h;
                                document.getElementById('myDiv').appendChild(li);
                        //  }
                        })
                    })

            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log('There has been a problem with your fetch operation: ' + error.message);
            });

        return (
            <div>
                <div></div>
            </div>
        )
    }

    _handleClick() {
        this.setState({showSeries: !this.state.showSeries});
    }
}
render( <Series />, document.getElementById('myDiv'));
```

Answer (score 1):

You are going about this slightly wrong in terms of thinking in React. Don't use `document.CreateElement()` to create divs. These aren't virtual elements that you want in React. You don't dynamically create html in React either, you dynamically create the data in the html or the conditions that render that html (booleans).

Note: If you want to do the API call more than once then you should use the [React lifecycle methods](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html) and probably `componentDidUpdate`. You should not be calling api methods in `render()` as this should only be for constructing virtual html.

On the first render, `buttonText` will be undefined but we don't care

```
import React from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';

const SHOWN_BUTTON_TEXT = "Show Series";
const HIDDEN_BUTTON_TEXT = "Hide Series";

class Series extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();

        //Bind in the constructor instead so we don't create a new function every render like you were doing
        this._handleOnClick = this._handleOnClick.bind(this);
        this.fetchSeries= this.fetchSeries.bind(this);

        this.state = {
            buttonText: HIDDEN_BUTTON_TEXT,
            showSeries: false,
            listItems: {}
        };
    }

    render() {
        return (<div>
                    <button onClick={this._handleOnClick}>{this.state.buttonText}</button>
                    <ul>
                        {this.state.listItems.map(item => <Item {...item}/>)}
                    </ul>
                </div>
        );
    }
    _handleOnClick() {
        this.setState({showSeries: !this.state.showSeries});
        this.setState({buttonText: SHOWN_BUTTON_TEXT ? this.state.showSeries : HIDDEN_BUTTON_TEXT})
    }
    fetchSeries() {
       var myInit = {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: new Headers({
                'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
            }),
        }
        var myRequest = new Request('data.json', myInit);
        fetch(myRequest)
            .then(function (response) {
                return response.json()
                    .then(function (json) {
                        this.setState({listItems: json});
                    }.bind(this)

            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log('There has been a problem with your fetch operation: ' + error.message);
            });
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        this.fetchSeries();
    }
}
```

[Stateless function](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/components-and-props.html#functional-and-class-components)

```
//Instead of passing in props as argument we can pass in the values directly
function Item ({t, c, h}) {
    return (
        <li>
            Name: {t},
            Genre: {c},
            Hit Count: {h}
        </li>
    );
}

render( <Series />, document.getElementById('myDiv'));
```